# Python requests script with proxies does not work in Docker container on Windows

Tags: django, windows, docker, python-requests, proxy

I have Docker installed on both Windows and Linux, and I have a dockerized Django app running on both operating systems.
When I execute this script in the Django shell on Linux, it correctly returns the IP of the proxy server, as expected.
However, when I run the same script on Windows, it returns my external IP address instead.

```
import requests
request = requests.get(url='https://httpbin.org/ip', proxies={
    'http': proxy_url,
    'https': proxy_url,
    'socks5': proxy_url
})
print(request.text)
```

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?